# JSF @ViewAccessScoped equivalent in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsf

am migrating jsf application into Spring boot. I would like to know what is equivalent scope in spring boot for JSF @ViewAccessScoped

Comment: JSF doesn't have a native `@ViewAccessScoped` annotation. That's part of DeltaSpike library. JSF only has a `@ViewScoped` annotation. Please reconfirm and if necessary re-run your research using the correct keyword because there are lots of resources instructing how to remap the `@ViewScoped` in Spring.

Comment: Ok. So I can Implement it in spring boot as well right.?

Comment: "Spring Boot" is ultimately just a library which enables launching a WAR application as if it were a JAR application. It has really no significance here. Just research using plain "Spring" as keyword. The solution is exactly the same.