# I have an issue on migration JSF Apache myfaces CDI to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf

Am migrating JSF to Spring boot. I have some Apache myfaces CDI annotation like '`ViewAccessScoped`' and `@Inject WindowContext`. I have added dependency in pom.xml file. When I try to run an application. It throws error : illegal state exception : no org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.BenManageProvider in place ! Please ensure that you configured the CDI implementation of your choice properly. Can I use Apache  myfaces CDI in spring boot.? or is there any another way to resolve the issue.?

Comment: Why migrate to springboot from cdi? You obviously had reak java-ee container and now you don't. Sounds like a degradation.

Comment: 'reak' should have been 'a real'

Comment: My Project it was developed in JSF. Now I need to Migrate it to Spring boot. I have changed ManagedBean to Spring bean. Now I have Scope ViewAccessScoped and WindowContext it was apache.myfaces. When I run the Spring boot application throw error what I mentioned in question. Do I need to do any additional configuration to use CDI implementation.?

Comment: you can simple add a CDI implementation (OpenWebBeans is just ~0,5-1MB ;)) but then you have to use CDI beans instead of Spring or JSF ManagedBeans.
But as you already used ViewAcessScoped, this means that you already used CDI Beans and CODI.
I would migrate to CDI and DeltaSpike - and use CDI beans.

Comment: Ok. But I have changed framework from JSF to Spring boot. In JSF CDI working fine. But Spring boot it throw error. What is the configuration I need to use for CDI for spring boot.?

Comment: JSF cannot be 'changed to SpringBoot', totally 10000% different things. You can run JSF _**IN**_ springBoot. Do you actually know the technology you are using?

Comment: That's great. Ya. Can you answer for the question - org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.BenManageProvider in place ! Please ensure that you configured the CDI implementation of your choice properly. Why am facing this issue while using Spring boot.?

Comment: I feel reminded to this one by reading question and comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365364/jsf-viewaccessscoped-equivalent-in-spring-boot